# Does the BTC-e API have a method to transfer bitcoins?

Tags: api, btce

It seems crazy to me that one of the largest exchanges could forgo including a methed in their [API](https://btc-e.com/api/documentation) to transfer bitcoins from one address to another, but this seems to be what BTC-e has done.

Does anyone know of a way to transfer bitcoins using BTC-e's API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of July, on the wiki entry about them, they do not seem to have an API endpoint for "withdraw".

Source:

- https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/BTC-E#Withdraw_options
- https://btc-e.com/api/documentation

I'm sure it would be helpful for arbitrage reasons.